# Python 3 int division operator is returning a float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, integer, division

In one of my assignments I came across a weird implementation, and I was curious if it's a bug or the designed behavior.

In Python 3, division by `/` returns a floating point number, and `//` means integer division and should return an integer. I've discovered though that if either of the values is a float when doing integer division, it will return a float.

Example:

```
# These all work as expected
10 / 2
-> 5.0
11 / 2
-> 5.5
10 // 2
-> 5
11 // 2
-> 5
# Here things start to get weird
10.0 // 2
-> 5.0
10 // 2.0
-> 5.0
11.0 // 2
-> 5.0
```

Is this *supposed* to behave this way? If so, *why* does it behave this way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [PEP-238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/), which introduced the new division (emphasis mine):

> ### Semantics of Floor Division
>
> Floor division will be implemented in all the Python numeric types,
>   and will have the semantics of:
>
> ```py
> a // b == floor(a/b)
> ```
>
> except that the result type will be the common type into which *a* and
>   *b* are coerced before the operation.
>
> **Specifically, if *a* and *b* are of the same type, `a//b` will be of that type too.** If the inputs are of different types, they are first
>   coerced to a common type using the same rules used for all other
>   arithmetic operators.
>
> In particular, if *a* and *b* are both ints or longs, the result has the
>   same type and value as for classic division on these types (including
>   the case of mixed input types; `int//long` and `long//int` will both
>   return a long).
>
> **For floating point inputs, the result is a float.** For example:
>
> ```py
> 3.5//2.0 == 1.0
> ```
>
> For complex numbers, `//` raises an exception, since `floor()` of a
>   complex number is not allowed.
>
> For user-defined classes and extension types, all semantics are up to
>   the implementation of the class or type.

So yes, it is supposed to behave that way. *"`//` means integer division and should return an integer"* - not quite, it means **floor division** and should return something *equal to* an integer (you'd always expect `(a // b).is_integer()` to be true where either operand is a float).

Comment: Internally what is happening? For mixed, ints and floats, values are converted to floats and then float.__floordiv__ is called?

Comment: @Chris_Rands you mean in the CPython implementation? I don't know, you'd have to look into https://github.com/python/cpython

Comment: Is there a use case where it would be desired for you to get a float instead of an int, since there will never be anything to the right of the decimal point?

Comment: @Kayla if you always want an int, it's easy to be explicit and say `int(a // b)`. But in general this behaviour is consistent with [arithmetic conversions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#arithmetic-conversions) and other [binary arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), and e.g. `1 == 1.0` and behaves similarly enough for most use cases.

Comment: Interestingly, [PEP 3141](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141) proposes that the `__floordiv__` special method should always return an `Integral` instance, but that part of PEP 3141 never got implemented for the `float` type. See also https://bugs.python.org/issue22444.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this clarifies the situation:

> **/ Division**
>
> Divides left hand operand by right hand operand
>
> ```
> b / a = 2
> ```
>
> **// Floor Division**
>
> The division of operands where the result is the quotient in which the
>   digits after the decimal point are removed. But if one of the operands
>   is negative, the result is floored, i.e., rounded away from zero
>   (towards negative infinity)
>
> ```
> 9//2 = 4 and 9.0//2.0 = 4.0, -11//3 = -4, -11.0//3 = -4.0
> ```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm