# Why does x // y floor division with floats not return an integer in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I am dividing 2 floats (or ints as well) with double slash like

```
t = x // y
```

In this case `t` must be an integer number, but python returns it as `float`.

```
>>> x, y = 3.0, 2.0
>>> x // y
1.0
```

[By the convention and documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282799/python-3-int-division-operator-is-returning-a-float), the output type of `x // y` is `float` if at least one of `x` or `y` is `float`. My question is WHY is the convention that way: What is the advantage of getting the result in `float`, and not `int`?

For my understanding, floor division **always** returns an integer. So the relation `int(x//y) == x//y` always holds. While there are some corner cases such as `nan`, "integer floor division" also has corner cases such as division by zero.

So my question is why `float` is better? In what cases will it differ?

---

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282799/python-3-int-division-operator-is-returning-a-float) which asks if this is a bug. Instead, I want to know what is the reason why this behaviour is advantageous.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal *reproducible* example? What is your Python version?

Comment: `//` is the *floor division*. for ex, in py3 if you do `10//3` you will get `3` the whole number.

Comment: Using python 3.7. I tried to use a list with 'lst[x // y]' and relised I have to convert it to int. But in what case it won't be an int?

Comment: `t` doesn't have to be a natural number. Could be any integer. And it is.

Comment: It should get an ```int```, just tried to reproduce the problem. Check your Python version or just do ```t = int(x / y)``` which will give the same output.

Comment: `float` objects can represent natural numbers just fine. Don't equivocate between mathematical definitions and concrete, computer number formats. They are different.

Comment: @LeandroEsteban no, `float // float` -> `float`

Comment: Using lst[int(x // y) ] is what I am doing (didn't find how to mark it as "code" in a comment. if x // y is an integer in any case, why python returns float?

Comment: `In this case t must be a natural number` note that `1//float("nan") = nan`

Comment: Saying `t` must be a natural number is simply incorrect. Even between `int` operands, the range of `//` is **integers**, not just natural numbers.

Comment: @KamilCuk This is true as well to float.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well, why setting the convention like that? Could it make any problem to determine float // float -> int ? I don't understand what we achive from the float as returned value

Comment: if you ask for the "why" your question will get closed for a different reason: which is, that it is primarily opnion based and doesn't fit this site

Comment: Can you clarify what you would consider a valid answer? Do you want an actual quote from the Python developers? Do you accept logical arguments why ``float, float -> float`` is advantageous?

Comment: Why is this *not* a duplicate of the original dupe target [Python 3 int division operator is returning a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282799/python-3-int-division-operator-is-returning-a-float) The question explicitly asks "Is this supposed to behave this way? If so, **why does it behave this way?**".

Comment: valid answer will be any answer that will give me an idea that there is a reason to return float and not int. I don't see in the question you linked an answer to that question

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Forcing `//` to be `(float, float) -> int` would not have any benefit, but unnecessary cost and type loss whenever `-> float` is sufficient.

---

In general, computation of `//` when any operand is a `float` is only correct if performed as `float`: a `float` operand may contain a fractional part that cannot be represented as an integer.

```py
>>> 4.3 // 1.1
3.0
>>> int(4.3) // int(1.1)
4
```

As such, `//` for any `float` operand is inherently a `float` computation and yields such a result ([CPython purely uses C `double` arithmetic](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b5f87b93a542082551c67538523d318f0d46e16e/Objects/floatobject.c#L687)). Providing the result as `int` would still compute the result as `float` and merely convert it to `int` – there would be no gain in precision.

With the behaviour specified by PEP 238, programmers can decide for themselves whether they desire to enforce `int` type or prefer the real `float` result.