# What happens behind the scene of floor division in Python?

Tags: python, floor-division

The [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) about the floor division in Python says,

> The / (division) and // (floor division) operators yield the quotient of their arguments. The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type. Division of integers yields a float, while floor division of integers results in an integer; the result is that of mathematical division with the ‘floor’ function applied to the result.

I'm focusing on the last line, that says,

> the result is that of mathematical division with the ‘floor’ function applied to the result

I get a `float` in:

```py
>>> 10//2.0
5.0
```

But an `integer` in:

```py
>>> import math
>>> math.floor(10/2.0)
5
```

So it's clearly not the `math.floor` function that Python floor division is using. I want to know what exact procedure is Python following to compute the floor division of two arguments.

Because when taking the floor division of `complex` numbers, Python says,

```py
>>> (2+3j)//(4+5j)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't take floor of complex number.
```

That means Python takes the division and then applies some sort of floor function. What really is it?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question about how this works (which might be implementation-dependent, I'm not sure), but see [this question about whether the behaviour is expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49282799/354577).

Comment: @ThierryLathuille what do you mean by "builtin `floor`".

Comment: @Chris yeah the behavior is as expected. I read a similar question earlier. I just want to know what's happening behind the scene.

Comment: Well as I said earlier I suspect that's implementation-dependent. There isn't just one "Python", there are many: CPython, Jython, PyPy, IronPython, MicroPython, Brython...

Comment: This is indeed implementation specific as mentioned in the other comment.  For PyPy which is a rpython based implementation: https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/-/blob/branch/default/pypy/objspace/std/floatobject.py, look for `descr_floordiv` function, this is for float as numerator. Give it a try, its quite readable.

Comment: Both `int.__truediv__` (if its second argument is a `float`) and `float.__floordiv__` are defined to return a `float`.

Answer (score 2):

Compare (both from that page):

> the ‘floor’ function

> The function [`math.fmod()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fmod)

If they meant `math.floor`, they would've styled it like they styled `fmod`, i.e., as code and with `math.` prefix and with parentheses and with link. What they do mean there is just the mathematical [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). Not a Python function.

Digging into how CPython implements it, let's first disassemble:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('x // y')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (y)
              4 BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Looking up [`BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2afd1751dd9a35d4ec03b708e3e5cddd72c43f7e/Python/ceval.c#L1668):

```
        case TARGET(BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE): {
            PyObject *divisor = POP();
            PyObject *dividend = TOP();
            PyObject *quotient = PyNumber_FloorDivide(dividend, divisor);
            Py_DECREF(dividend);
            Py_DECREF(divisor);
            SET_TOP(quotient);
            if (quotient == NULL)
                goto error;
            DISPATCH();
        }
```

Looking up [`PyNumber_FloorDivide`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1b4552c5e8e925f24c15f707050f22c977171125/Objects/abstract.c#L999)

```
PyObject *
PyNumber_FloorDivide(PyObject *v, PyObject *w)
{
    return binary_op(v, w, NB_SLOT(nb_floor_divide), "//");
}
```

Looking up [`nb_floor_divide`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#sub-slots):

```
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
| Slot            | Type       | special methods |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
| ...             | ...        | ...             |
| nb_floor_divide | binaryfunc | __floordiv__    |
| ...             | ...        | ...             |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
```

Now `int` and `floor` both have their own:

```
>>> int.__floordiv__
<slot wrapper '__floordiv__' of 'int' objects>
>>> float.__floordiv__
<slot wrapper '__floordiv__' of 'float' objects>
```

Looking up the function for [the `float` one](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2afd1751dd9a35d4ec03b708e3e5cddd72c43f7e/Objects/floatobject.c#L1895):

```
static PyNumberMethods float_as_number = {
    ...
    float_floor_div,    /* nb_floor_divide */
    ...
};
```

Looking up [`float_floor_div`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2afd1751dd9a35d4ec03b708e3e5cddd72c43f7e/Objects/floatobject.c#L688):

```
static PyObject *
float_floor_div(PyObject *v, PyObject *w)
{
    double vx, wx;
    double mod, floordiv;
    CONVERT_TO_DOUBLE(v, vx);
    CONVERT_TO_DOUBLE(w, wx);
    if (wx == 0.0) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ZeroDivisionError, "float floor division by zero");
        return NULL;
    }
    _float_div_mod(vx, wx, &floordiv, &mod);
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(floordiv);
}
```

Looking up [`_float_div_mod`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2afd1751dd9a35d4ec03b708e3e5cddd72c43f7e/Objects/floatobject.c#L635):

```
static void
_float_div_mod(double vx, double wx, double *floordiv, double *mod)
{
    ...
    /* snap quotient to nearest integral value */
    if (div) {
        *floordiv = floor(div);
        if (div - *floordiv > 0.5) {
            *floordiv += 1.0;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And I think `floor` is from C, so depends on whatever C compiler was used to compile your CPython.

Comment: That clarifies that it's not `math.floor`, which I already figured out. But what's actually happening behind the scene? How Python is computing it?

Comment: Depends on the Python implementation and on the types of the operands. Like, at least in CPython, `3 // 2` uses `int.__floordiv__` and `3.0 // 2` uses `float.__floordiv__`. And then you can look at their source code as closely as desired.

Comment: @Fahim Added some more details.