# python - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'

Tags: python, typeerror

When I try and run my code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/exal/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    if powerOfTwoCheck(n) == True:
  File "/home/exal/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 4, in powerOfTwoCheck
    return (n & (n - 1)) == 0 and n > 0
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'
50.0
```

This error only occcurs when I use the `%` operator, everything else seems to function correctly when I remove it.

my code:

```py
# Collatz conjecture in python

def powerOfTwoCheck(n):
    return (n & (n - 1)) == 0 and n > 0
# If a number is a power of two then it will eventually lead to the 4-1 loop

n = 100
while True:
    if powerOfTwoCheck(n) == True:
        break
    elif n%2 == 0:  # checks if number is even
        n = n / 2
        print(n)
    elif n % 2 != 0:  # Checks if number is odd
        n = (n * 3) + 1
        print(n)
```

Why is it occuring and How would i fix it?

(sorry if this is formatted wrong or a bad question, I rarely use stack overflow)

Comment: Change the `n = n / 2`  to `n = n // 2`

Comment: That worked! But could you please explain why you have to use `//` instead of `/` ?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282799/python-3-int-division-operator-is-returning-a-float

Comment: In python3, `/` is float division, meaning, the result could be float number. You need integer division, `//`.

Comment: @excal.rs single slash is normal division while double slash is floor division, so 5/2 = 2.5 and  5//2==2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because in this:

```
elif n%2 == 0:  # checks if number is even
    n = n / 2
```

it converts n into a float that give error
you have to convert it into integer

end code will be

```
def powerOfTwoCheck(n):
    return (n & (n - 1)) == 0 and n > 0
n = 100
while True:
    if powerOfTwoCheck(n) == True:
        break
    elif n%2 == 0:
        n = int(n / 2)
        print(n)
    elif n % 2 != 0:
        n = (n * 3) + 1
        print(n)
```

You can use:

```
elif n%2 == 0:
    n = int(n / 2)
```

or

```
elif n%2 == 0:
    n = (n // 2)
```